# How to force ImageButton To Scale Like ImageView

Tags: android

I have an ImageView that scales down when I set the layout width to fill parent. But when I change it to an ImageButton, it doesn't scale. How do I get the ImageButton to look like the ImageView?

[image: Example]

Comment: Try  making image that it dont scale down

Comment: set it as the background and specify the button's height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [android:scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) attribute (set to center inside or something like that).

However, even if you can get it to scale, I am not sure if you'll get the result you want. The imagebutton displays a regular button, but with an image instead of text, that is you'll get the button-borders around your image. If the imageview works as you want it to, why don't you keep it as an imageview, but set the focusable and clickable attributes on it?

Answer (score 0):

As Jave suggested, set `scaleType` to `centerCrop`. And also set `padding` to `0dp` to take out button borders.